# Python print() command doesn't print everything on one line

Tags: python, list, printing

Can someone tell me why my output doesn't show every element in my list on one line. Instead it shows underneath each other. I'm not really sure why this is happening.

```
pon = '         \n   I   \n         '

list = [pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon]
for element in list:
    print(element,end='')
```

Comment: Why would it? Your strings contain newlines. Your output device doesn't know or care that they were part of the input to `print`, rather than added by `print`.

Comment: `print` adds a newline character at the end. You should read documentation and you will discover the `end` argument of print. Setting `end=""` will give you (almost) the desired behaviour.

Comment: @decadenza OP *did* use `end=''`.

Comment: Ops. I missed that! Sorry! Then it's the newline characters in `pon`...

Answer (score 0):

Because the '\n' in your string is a character that means new line

Basicly, everytime there's \n in a string, it's gonna make your print go to a new line

You can ''cancel'' the \n by adding a new ''`\`'' if your objective was printing \n

(like that `\\n`)

EDIT:

```
end=''
```

means that by itself each print isn't gonna add a new line, but it doesn't count for the one in your string, just the one naturally added by print function

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is a newline character. You have `\n`s in your string, so they will be printed as a new line. See this example:

```py
s = 'First line\nSecond line'
print(s)
```

Output:

```
First line
Second line
```

To print a literal `\`, escape it with another `\`:

```py
pon = '         \\n   I   \\n         '
```

This outputs:

```
         \n   I   \n                  \n   I   \n                  \n   I   \n                  \n   I   \n                  \n   I   \n                  \n   I   \n                  \n   I   \n                  \n   I   \n                  \n   I   \n
```

Notes:

1. Using a keyword like `list` as a variable name id not encouraged. Use something like `my_list` instead
2. Instead of `[pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon]`, use `[pon] * 10`

Comment: I actually meant to print a 9x9 empty string

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `repr` for string to print in with `\n`

```
pon = "       \n   I   \n       "

list = [pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon, pon]
for element in list:
    print(repr(element),end='')
```

**Output:**

```
'       \n   I   \n       ''       \n   I   \n       ''       \n   I   \n       ''       \n   I   \n       ''       \n   I   \n       ''       \n   I   \n       ''       \n   I   \n       ''       \n   I   \n       ''       \n   I   \n       '
```

Comment: That has quotes, which the OP doesn't want.